# How can I make my Discord bot respond to mentions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make my Discord bot respond to mentions like "@TLG-bot#5376 how old are you?"
I'm using Discord.py to achieve this.

I was trying to turn my bot into a conversation bot, but no need now :)

Comment: NOTE: I have done my research numerous times and haven't found an answer.

Comment: But you don't mention that (so how could we have known) and you don't show any code to back up that claim (so you might have not done that, even if you say so). Show your code and point out what part of it fails.

Comment: Your research should show in your question. Just like "I fixed your issue " wouldn't help you unless I post an answer, you saying 'I did my research' is pointless without proof...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discord handles mentions in a way that is not obvious from the looks of it.

Every mention is actually a string like this: `<@user_id>` (or `<@!user_id>` if the member has a nickname.) You can try this by copying your bots user ID and replacing `user_id` with it (e.g. `<@330407844660641792>`)

If you are using the `ext.commands` framework included in discord.py, you can use [`when_mentioned`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L55-L61) as your prefix in the `commands.Bot(...)` initialization.

You can also use [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) to get a list of [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) that were mentioned in the message. Note that this will parse mentions from the whole message, not just the beginning, and will parse every member mentioned, not just your bot.

Otherwise use the [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) event to parse the string manually from the contents of the message with whichever method you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Despite your comment stating you have done your reasearch, you dont seem to have read the first link on google when searching for discord.py, which is their API reference. [Thats this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

All joking aside, inside that there is a function called

> **discord.on_message(message)**
>
> Called when a message is created and sent to a server.

You can use this function to be told every time a message is sent, and then scan this for your bots username.

Comment: Using the command framework is probably better than on_message.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix